# gcc: fatal error: no input files when compiling and linking a resource file with Code::Blocks

Tags: c, gcc, windows-7, cygwin, windres

I grow tired from badly-made non-working or unnecessarily obfuscated user-hostile tools and programs.

I am using Code::Blocks set to compile with Cygwin GCC (Compiler toolchain directory: `C:\msys64\usr`), I add a `.rc` file within my project and then when I compile I get this:

> === Build: Debug in Test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===
>
> UsersAl3Desktopresource.rc || No such file or directory
>
> warning: '-x c' after last input file has no effect
>
> error: no input files

Why is it removing the backslashes from the resource file path?
Also as you can see from this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rEBa.png), the file path of the resource file does not contain any spaces or weird characters, neither does the windres.exe, which is located in `C:\msys64\usr\bin`

---

What causes this issue and how do I fix it?

Comment: This sounds seriously confused.  You say you are using Cygwin, but you reference `C:\msys64\usr`, which is different environment.  As to *why* you see `UsersAl3Desktopresource.rc`, it's because in a POSIX environment '\' is an escape character, so except for specific cases (e.g. "\n" = newline) escaping an arbitrary character has no effect, e.g. so "\Users" is equivalent to "Users".  For a start, you could try replacing those backslashes with regular slashes ("/Users"), but I suspect there is far more wrong in your environment than this alone will fix.